# Installing Compass & Susy on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ruby, ubuntu-12.04, compass-sass

I'm trying to install Compass and Susy on my Ubuntu 12.04.

What I have tried are the following steps on the console:

```
sudo apt-get install rubygems1.8
sudo gem install rubygems-update # Instead of sudo gem update --system
sudo update_rubygems
sudo gem install compass # Installing Compass & Sass
sudo gem install susy
```

So the gems are installed and will be listed when I do the following command:

```
gem list
```

But now, when I try to create a new compass project with

```
compass create project
```

I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/bin/compass: /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

My current ruby version is 1.8.7. So I installed ruby 1.9.1 and get it working.
The console still says the current ruby version is 1.8.7

My question: Do I have to run with both ruby versions to get that working? Is there another way under ubuntu? It's working, I know, but it's a bit confusing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using Ubuntu's package manager for multiple ruby versions is a bit of a lost cause.

*Most* people use [rvm](http://rvm.io), which allows you to install and switch between multiple rubies very easily.

Other popular options are [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/) and [chruby](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby). It's just a question of personal preference, but I'd say that rvm has the slight edge for beginners.

Also, I wouldn't recommend installing ruby 1.9.1 - it's best to use 1.9.3 as there are some compatibility issues with other 1.9.x versions.

You can then install compass and sass via ruby gems (rather than aptitude):

```
$ gem install compass
$ gem install sass
```

Answer (score 5):

This simple command works on ubuntu 14.10

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-compass
```

Comment: if using Arch linux you can run  `yaourt ruby-compass`

Answer (score 2):

RVM is awesome and really easy to install. I managed to install rvm, compass, and sass with these commands in my terminal:

Firstly:

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails --autolibs=enabled --ruby=1.9.3
```

This will instal rvm, it will put a command in ~/.bash_profile to load rvm automatically, except this isn't what Ubuntu uses so put this line into your ~/.bashrc file:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

Then simply run:

```
gem install compass
gem install susy #(or sass)
```

Answer (score 1):

Install build-essentials and ruby-dev packages to install compass without errors.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install ruby
sudo apt-get install ruby-dev
sudo gem install compass
```

Answer (score 0):

Masterchief's answer is close, but didn't work for me. This web page provided a clear and reliably working way to install rvm on my ubuntu server instance: http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/